# Nginx Access PHP in a subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to access the subdirectory /presskit which has an index.php and a sheets.php that this presskit system uses. Unfortunately I can't quite figure out how to get access to it, I get either 404, get redirected to my main page, or it just says unable to handle request.

The file I'm trying to access is located at
/var/www/html/spreadcamp.com/public_html/presskit/index.php

which I'm trying to access by going to https://spreadcamp.com/presskit/index.php

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name spreadcamp.com www.spreadcamp.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    root /var/www/html/spreadcamp.com/public_html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name spreadcamp.com www.spreadcamp.com;

    proxy_cache one;
    

    gzip off;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ^~ /presskit {
        index index.php;
        alias /var/www/html/spreadcamp.com/public_html/presskit;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /presskit/index.php last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            }
    }


    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `location ^~ /presskit {` looks weird, and I think it should just be `location /presskit {` which is literally just "if it starts with" and doesn't need regex. Also, because `presskit` is a folder with one-to-one naming between FS and URL, you shouldn't need the alias. Lastly, I think you can remove the `if` and inner `location` block and just use `try_files $uri $uri/ /presskit/index.php?$args;`, although there might be some extra things in the QS for that specific program which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I've done those changes as you suggested but it still shows me "HTTP Error 500 This page isn’t working" maybe I did it wrong this is what it looks like now `location /presskit {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /presskit/index.php?$args;
        }`

Comment: Check the access log to see with path it try to access.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the error.log which showed me that simplexml did not exist and I fixed my problem by installing it (Ubuntu) using ``sudo apt-get install php-xml``